# How to get value of hidden input field not in same the order with regular expression

Tags: input, expression, field, hidden

I want to get value of hidden input field

```
<FORM onsubmit="javascript:return add();" method=post action=addMess.php>
....
<INPUT name=sysess2 value=1234 type=hidden>
....
</FORM>
```

eg :

```
<INPUT type=hidden name=hyds2 value=1234>
<input name=hyds2 type=hidden value=1234>
<INPUT value=1234 type=hidden name=hyds2>
```

Anyone know how I can do that with regular expression ?

Answer (score 0):

To get upper or lowercase, I use this regex  `(?i)(?<=\<input.*value\=).*(?=\>)`
Perhaps with the use of pipe (|) for this regex I can get multiple matches ?